# In Jquery mobile, Header and footers are always hiding, when clicking inside the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need, header and footer always fixed position.

I don't want like the below url page. What will i do?. Help me........
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html

(In the above url, if u clicked inside the page. The header and footer will hide). I don't want like this

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If anyone still finds this question and realises the above no longer works, like I did, the correct way to do it (which is correct today, 23/May/2012) is now:

`<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">`

Comment: Works like a charm and the app seems more "buggy less" with no flickering, thanks!

Comment: maybe it should be the default

Comment: Worked great. Toggling a checkbox was hiding header/footer, this worked like a charm. Also seemed to cancel out the click delay as well.

Comment: funny thing this is included in the 1.2 documentation but completely omitted in the 1.4.5 demos documentation. jQuery Mobile documentation really needs a rewrite, at least for latest version. Thanks so much, you saved my day

Answer (score 16):

Use `data-tap-toggle="false"` AND `data-hide-during-focus=""`.

The second one will prevent fixed toolbars from hiding [when you click an input](http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/#option-hideDuringFocus).

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Other solutions have failed. Thx

Answer (score 5):

I managed to do it using a fixed footer:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
    <div data-role="navbar"> 
        <ul> 
            <li></li> 
            <li></li> 
            <li></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

and some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#containerPage').live('pagecreate', function (event) {

        $.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);

    });
</script>
```

where `#containerPage` is my main page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="containerPage" data-fullscreen="true">
..
</div>
```

**I've tried and tested this solution with jQuery Mobile v1.0rc1. downloaded October, 13th 2011**

Comment: thanks LeftyX... I commented "$.fixedToolbars.toggle(stateBefore);" statement in jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js. Its also working... But your answers is safe for me. thanks

Answer (score 5):

`data-tap-toggle="false"` saved me the same headache!

It's a good feature. I'm surprised I missed it in the docs.

Comment: that's the same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712780/1545993) ...???

Answer (score 1):

data-tap-toggle="false" works ok with jQueryMobile 1.1.0 and PhoneGap 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is dated, however it didn't help me 100%. Below is the solution I came to after some refined googling, decided to post it here as this was my first result.

My problem was that the header and footer would hide when tapping an input, regardless of whether the default behaviour was used. I was using the amazing DateBox.

Manually updating the DOM header/footer with data-tap-toggle='false' didn't do anything, but this would have saved me some time:

```
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggleBlacklist: "input[data-role=datebox]" });
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggleBlacklist: "input[data-role=datebox]" });
```

For whatever reason, disabling tap toggles this way solved my issue as well as showing me a short-hand for disabling it across a large number of pages.

Comment: You could try `data-hide-during-focus=""`. See: http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/#option-hideDuringFocus

Answer (score 0):

`data-hide-during-focus=""` is only for the input type which need focus,if you click anywhere in the page and the problem happen then you need to use `data-tap-toggle="false"`. put this only in the fixed position div

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" 
   data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="" data-theme="b"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using `data-hide-during-focus=""`, It's working now!