# jquery mobile static footer navbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Found this answer [In Jquery mobile, Header and footers are always hiding, when clicking inside the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925246/in-jquery-mobile-header-and-footers-are-always-hiding-when-clicking-inside-the)

The only difference that I have is I do NOT have data-fullscreen="true" but have a data-cache="never".

footer bar keeps fading in and out.  Just want footer navbar to be on bottom of screen without fades.

```
<div data-role="page" data-cache="never" id="mainPage">
<script>
$('#mainPage').live('pagecreate', function (event) {

    $.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);

});
</script>
....header stuff
<div data-role="content" id="mainContent">
....
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      ... 4 li's
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Here we go.  How is this done?
http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/#../../docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Header loads immediately but not footer.  Would like for my footer to act like the header of that page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927504/jquery-mobile-bottom-navbar-aka-sticky-footer Yeah  I can't figure this out either. Its really annoying.

Comment: At the end, iScroll was the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is fixed in jQueryMobile 1.1 rc1.  See [this link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html)

Use **data-tap-toggle="false"** on your footer.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
There's just one problems when you're scrolling a list: the navbar disappears but it reappers as soon as you stop scrolling.
You can see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/DcajJ/).

Comment: Yes, the footer does stick "actually better" with it, but looking for more native feel where fades in / out DO NOT happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
             $.support.touchOverflow = true;

              $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
              $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);

        });
```

This works. Tested in Android 2.3