# jquery mobile static footer without toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a fixed footer

```
<div data-role="page" id="next_collection" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="elw">
        Title
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="min-height: 246px;">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer_nav" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#business_hours"><img src="images/icon.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works on Android and iPod, but on iPhone 4s it toggles (hide/show) the footer if you touch the screen. I tried to fix it like in this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962961/jquery-mobile-static-footer-navbar/8820876#8820876) but this does not work anymore. For `$.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled()` i get:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars is undefined
```

How to stop the footer from toggle in the newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @commadelimited says, the toggle has been a new feature not available in prior versions.

The meta data to add to your header or footer to remove that toggle feature is:

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

so, in your case, the footer should looks like:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="footer_nav" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#business_hours"><img src="images/icon.png" /></a>
</div>
```

And here should be some kind of reference from their site: [link to google search](https://www.google.es/search?q=site%3ajquerymobile.com%20data-tap-toggle&oq=site%3ajquerymobile.com%20data-tap-toggle&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5183j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3ajquerymobile.com%20%22data-tap-toggle%22)