# jquery mobile fixed (always on top) header

Tags: jquery, mobile, header, fixed

I have looked through other posts on stackoverflow but they seem too complicated for such a simple task.

All I want to do is have a fixed header on top my mobile app that will ALWAYS stay there even when I scroll the "listview". Please tell the simplest way to achieve this. Right now when I scroll down the header does appear but after tapping it goes away. How can I hack this jquery go away behaviour?
Thanks!

I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Testing Jquery</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two, same issues, are answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925246/in-jquery-mobile-header-and-footers-are-always-hiding-when-clicking-inside-the

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962961/jquery-mobile-static-footer-navbar

Answer (score 4):

[Check this doc from jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) .
Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be a comment.